# Camel doesn't recognize faults as exceptions

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, fuseesb

I've encountered a very strange problem with Fuse ESB 7.1.0: when a cxf endpoint produces a fault, then this fault doesn't look like an exception, so I can't process it using doCatch construction.
The cxf endpoint is defined as follows:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="cxf-ep" address="${ws.url}" serviceClass="MyServiceClass">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

And here is a short code snippet where I expect an exception:

```
<doTry>
    <to uri="cxf:bean:cxf-ep" />
    <doCatch>
        <exception>org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault</exception>
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
        <to uri="log:exceptions?multiline=true&amp;showCaughtException=true&amp;showStackTrace=true&amp;showBody=true&amp;showProperties=true&amp;showHeaders=true&amp;level=ERROR" />
    </doCatch>
</doTry>
```

I've tried to add handleFault="true" attribute to both a camel context and a route, but without success.
A bundle with a similar parameters and routes has worked as expected on Fuse ESB/ServiceMix 4.4.1, so it looks like a regression or maybe something has changed in camel in the new release?

Another interesting moment is that when a web server is not available, then camel produces org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault, so it can't be handled as an exception!

Camel version: 2.10.0.fuse-71-047

Comment: I use a cxf jax-ws client bean as a workaround currently.

Comment: This is also being discussed here: http://fusesource.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=4662&tstart=0